# Is there a way to prevent OnLayoutExit script trigger from triggering when a script changes the layout?

Tags: database, layout, triggers, exit, filemaker

We have a layout in our FileMaker database with an OnLayoutExit script trigger that checks if the user left required fields empty. However, as part of standard use of the layout another script is called that populates fields across several tables. To do this the script performs several `Go To Layout()` function calls. This is triggering the OnLayoutExit script trigger from the original layout. The user is unlikely to have filled out the required fields by the time this script is called. When this script is finished, it returns back to the original layout, so the empty fields are not an issue for us. However, our OnLayoutExit script is warning the user of the empty fields.

I'm curious if there is a way to differentiate between the user switching layouts and a script switching layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution could be not to have the script leave the layout. Instead of  switching to another layout, open a new window with the target layout, do what needs to be done, then close the new window.

To answer your question as asked: leaving a layout is leaving a layout, no matter how it's done. The only way to distinguish between the cases is to have your triggered script look at the contents of a field/variable/script parameter and adjust its action accordingly.

---

Another option is to enter Find mode before leaving the layout (assuming the trigger is only enabled in Browse mode). But that could be rather confusing when you review the script at a later time.

Comment: Ahhh you've actually inspired me to try using a global variable. Barring that I may give the new window solution a try. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you don't want to use a new window (which IMHO is the preferable solution), then the next best option would be to trigger the script with a parameter of `Get(ScriptName)`. Then you can tell when user triggered the script because the parameter will be empty. That saves you the bother of setting (and resetting!) a global variable.

Comment: Thank you again for your knowledge! The `Get(ScriptName)` really seemed like a perfect solution, but I couldn't get that to work. Ended up going with the global variable. If this ends up more complex/annoying later down the road I'll try out the new window solution.